# Why is a map that is given by a finite collection of translation maps volume preserving? (Part of a proof of Minkowski's theorem)

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, integer-lattices

The claim was made in my textbook as a part of a proof of Minkowski's theorem without any explanation. Intuively it feels correct, but that's not enough in math.

The map in question is $$\frac{1}{2} S\rightarrow\mathcal{F},\ \frac{1}{2} a\rightarrow w_{\frac{1}{2} a}.$$ Here $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded symmetric convex set and $w\in\mathcal{F}$ is in the fundamental parallelpiped of lattice $L$, so it is also a bounded, symmetric and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Vector $a$ is of course in $S$. 
Every vector $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as $t=v_t+w_t$ where $v_t\in L,\ w_t\in\mathcal{F}$, so that's what the subscript is in reference to.

I don't know if the map matters though because the wording makes it seem that the claim should be generally true.

Comment: What is the textbook you are following?

Comment: An Introduction to Mathematical Cryptography by Hoffstein. The claim is made in the chapter Lattices and cryptography, page 398 in my edition.

Comment: Does he call a map $\varphi: x \to \alpha x$ for some constant $\alpha$ as translation?

Comment: This is the only time I've come across he mentioning translations in the book. He calls the map I've described as "given by finite collection of translation maps", with suggests he calls $\ \frac{1}{2} a\rightarrow w_{\frac{1}{2} a}$ a translation. This also is weird, because this map certainly doesn't move all points the same distance in the same direction.